# django pwa error = cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls

Tags: python, django, progressive-web-apps

Hello I am using `Django 4.0.3` and I try to use `django-pwa` in my project but when i runserver i get the below error.

I followed this tutorial [geeksforgeeks:make-pwa-of-a-django-project](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/make-pwa-of-a-django-project/) for including progressive web application feature in my project.

I think `url` from `django.conf.urls` is deprecated.

I am sure that must exist some solutions...

Help me please.

**Error**

```
File "C:\Users\Republic Of Computer\Desktop\Master cours et TD\python\tberra3lipy\venv\lib\site-packages\pwa\urls.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls import url
ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls' (C:\Users\Republic Of Computer\Desktop\Master cours et TD\python\tberra3lipy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('donation/',include('donation.urls',namespace='donation')),
    path('',include('pwa.urls')),
]+static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'pwa',
    'accounts',
    'donation',
    
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'src.urls' 
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#pwa
PWA_SERVICE_WORKER_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/js', 'serviceworker.js')
PWA_APP_NAME = 'tberra3li'
PWA_APP_DESCRIPTION = "app for blood donors"
PWA_APP_THEME_COLOR = '#000000'
PWA_APP_BACKGROUND_COLOR = '#ffffff'
PWA_APP_DISPLAY = 'standalone'
PWA_APP_SCOPE = '/'
PWA_APP_ORIENTATION = 'any'
PWA_APP_START_URL = '/'
PWA_APP_STATUS_BAR_COLOR = 'default'
PWA_APP_ICONS = [
    {
        'src': 'static/assets/img/icon-160x160.png',
        'sizes': '160x160'
    }
]
PWA_APP_ICONS_APPLE = [
    {
        'src': 'static/assets/img/icon-160x160.png',
        'sizes': '160x160'
    }
]
PWA_APP_SPLASH_SCREEN = [
    {
        'src': 'static/assets/img/icon.png',
        'media': '(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)'
    }
]
PWA_APP_DIR = 'ltr'
PWA_APP_LANG = 'en-US'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`django.conf.urls` is deprecated in `Django 4`, so you cannot use `django-pwa` with your version of Django, you need to use `Django 3`. Otherwise you could fork/edit `django-pwa` to replace `django.conf.urls.url` (that is used in this [file](https://github.com/silviolleite/django-pwa/blob/0ff60e7afaf23d6883d593554b93e54bb56e41fe/pwa/urls.py)) with `django.urls.path`, see this [pull request](https://github.com/silviolleite/django-pwa/pull/82).